# Python speechrecognition 'Child Process error'

Tags: python, python-2.7, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

So I am trying out the speechrecognition module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) in python and an trying out the below code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:                # use the default microphone as the audio source
    audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
except LookupError:                            # speech is unintelligible
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

When this runs I get the following error:

```
Thomass-MBP:Turret thomashitch$ python Speech.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Speech.py", line 4, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SpeechRecognition-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 208, in listen
    return AudioData(source.RATE, self.samples_to_flac(source, frame_data))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SpeechRecognition-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 129, in samples_to_flac
    raise ChildProcessError("FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application using brew install flac")
NameError: global name 'ChildProcessError' is not defined
```

Extra information: It took a few seconds after running the code before it crashed and produced the error.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error and how I might solve it?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: It seems you have to install Flac tools :  https://xiph.org/flac/download.html

Comment: Thanks I have ensured Flac is installed but same error is still occuring.

Comment: have you installed it using brew ?

Comment: No I installed using the .tar.gz file instead.

Comment: The flac comamnd-line seems to be only available when installed with Homebrew : ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" then brew install flac

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work try upgrade your python version to 3.6.6 or 3.8.4 it is working in these versions of python

```
import speech_recognition as sr
        
        def speechrecognizer(): 
            try:
                r = sr.Recognizer()
                with sr.Microphone() as audio:
                    print('Listening...')
                    voice = r.listen(audio)
                    print("Thinking...")
                    query = r.recognize_google(voice,language='en-in')
                    str(query)
                    print(f"{query}") 
        
            except:
              pass
            return query
```